# Asynchronous messaging that doesn't get triggered until transaction is committed using Spring Integration

Tags: transactions, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration and I have the following scenario.  Today, I have my Dao's send an event to a publish-subscribe channel when an entity gets saved or updated or deleted.  It is basically implemented like so:

An event gateway interface:

```
public interface DaoEventGateway {
  @Gateway
  void sendEvent(EntityEvent event);
}
```

A DAO:

```
public class ADao {

  private DaoEventGateway gateway;

  public void save(A aEntity) {
    ... do some stuff to save it.
    fireEvent(aEntity, EntityType.SAVE);
  }

  protected void fireEvent(A entity, EventType eventType) {
    if (eventGateway != null) {
      EntityEvent event =
                    new EntityEvent(entity, eventType);
      eventGateway.sendEvent(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Some kind of listener for the events:

```
public class AEventLoggingService {
  public void receiveEvent(Event event) {
    A event = event.getEntity();
    Long id = event.getId();
    ... look up some associations based on the id ...
    ... log something about the event ...
  }
}
```

Configured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd">

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="aEventChannel" />

    <int:gateway id="aEventGateway" service-interface="com.factorlab.persistence.DaoEventGateway"
                 default-request-channel="aEventChannel">
        <int:method name="sendEvent" request-channel="aEventChannel" />
    </int:gateway>

    <bean id="aDao" class="com.factorlab.ADao">
        <property name="eventGateway" ref="aEventGateway" />
    </bean>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="aEventChannel"
                           ref="aEventLoggingService" method="receiveEvent" />

</beans>
```

Now everything works fine right now except for performance because I think all of the subscribers are acting in the same thread (and same transaction) as the publisher.

I would like to decouple the work done by the listeners from the work done in the DAO and make it asynchronous.  However, the listeners can depend on the thing they got the notification about already being in the database.  So, I don't want the message to be sent (or at least not received) until after the transaction has been committed.

Is there a standard approach for this? What advice do people have for how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the record to database with a pending status. Then poll the database for pending records based on that pending status. This process effectively decouples the current synchronous processing and helps what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Is the new [transaction synchronization in Spring Integration 2.2](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/09/26/whats-new-in-spring-integration-2-2-part-2-transaction-synchronization/) what you're looking for? The Release Candidate is out, so I assume the final version should be available soon, though I'm not sure how soon.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  However, reading that post, it sounds like I don't need that special synchronization.  I think I can use existing synchronization. What I am looking for is bridging the publish-subscribe channel with an asynchronous channel between the publish-subscribe channel and the service-activator.  I do need to synchronize the transaction with the channel, but I am open to already transactional channels.  I just can't find any examples doing what I want.